# Pandas Calculation Optimisation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV-File with 17 million rows. It's a MSEG table from SAP.
Within those rows, there are data columns like EBELN, EBELP, DMBTR. what i want to do is to sum DMBTR for all rows where EBELN & EBELP is identical.

this is what i do:

```
import pandas as pd
mseg_table = ['MANDT', 'MBLNR', 'MJAHR', 'DMBTR', 'ERFMG', 'ERFME', 'EBELN', 'EBELP', 'LFBJA', 'LFBNR', 'SGTXT', 'WEMPF']
mseg = pd.read_table('c:/3wayvisual/MSEG.CSV', sep=';', header=None, dtype=str, names=mseg_table)
mseg.drop(['MANDT', 'MBLNR', 'MJAHR', 'ERFME', 'ERFMG', 'LFBJA', 'SGTXT', 'LFBNR', 'WEMPF'], axis=1, inplace=True)
seg['DMBTR'] = mseg['DMBTR'].astype(float)
mseg = mseg.dropna(subset=['EBELN'])
```

This gives me the Dataframe cleared of all "unimportant" data. here is a example of a EBELN Number from the DataFrame:

```
print(mseg.loc[mseg['EBELN'] == '0025284220'])

        DMBTR       EBELN  EBELP
4600   628.51  0025284220  00010
4611   624.94  0025284220  00010
4617  1251.67  0025284220  00010
4625   623.16  0025284220  00010
4644  1543.56  0025284220  00020
4655  2320.83  0025284220  00020
4661  1543.56  0025284220  00020
4666   768.11  0025284220  00020
4671   765.36  0025284220  00020
4685   672.84  0025284220  00030
4693   673.70  0025284220  00030
4703   669.44  0025284220  00030
4737  1350.80  0025284220  00030
4745  1349.09  0025284220  00030
4746   672.84  0025284220  00030
4748   673.70  0025284220  00030
```

now the bad part begins, i get the number of unique occurencies for EBELN and EBELP.

```
ebeln_unique = mseg.EBELN.unique()
ebelp_unique = mseg.EBELP.unique()
```

After that, i create a list of sub-DataFrames for each EBELN&EBELP-Kombination.

```
mseg_teil = []
ebeln_index=0
for x in ebeln_unique:
    ebelp_index=0
    for y in ebelp_unique:
        if len(mseg[(mseg['EBELN'] == ebeln_unique[ebeln_index]) & (mseg['EBELP'] == ebelp_unique[ebelp_index])]) != 0:
            mseg_teil.append(mseg[(mseg['EBELN'] == ebeln_unique[ebeln_index]) & (mseg['EBELP'] == ebelp_unique[ebelp_index])])
            ebelp_index = ebelp_index + 1
        else:
            ebelp_index = ebelp_index + 1
    ebeln_index = ebeln_index + 1
```

Now i go through this List, sum the DMBTR of each DataFrame, and add a new row to a new Dataframe.

```
mseg_teil_index = 0
mseg_summiert = pd.DataFrame() 
for z in mseg_teil:
    mseg_pop = []
    EBELN = 0
    EBELP = 0
    DMBTR = 0
    mseg_pop = mseg_teil[mseg_teil_index]
    DMBTR = mseg_pop.DMBTR.sum()
    EBELN = mseg_pop.EBELN[0]
    EBELP = mseg_pop.EBELP[0]
    '''zeile_summiert = pd.DataFrame({'DMBTR': [DMBTR], 'EBELN': [EBELN], 'EBELP': [EBELP]})'''
    mseg_summiert = mseg_summiert.append({'DMBTR': DMBTR, 'EBELN': EBELN, 'EBELP': EBELP}, ignore_index = True)
    mseg_teil_index = mseg_teil_index + 1
```

this is working well, but it takes a lot of time and memory of the machine. The operation will be on a server at some time in the future, but the MSEG dataframe will have about 10 columns.

this is the result of my current example data:

```
    DMBTR       EBELN       EBELP
0   21771.54    0029784218  00010
1   347.00      0029783465  00050
2   2839.00     0029783464  00060
3   458.80      0029784290  00010
4   35266.56    0029779778  00010
5   10241.36    0029783913  00010
6   10413.14    0029783912  00010
7   10208.64    0029783912  00020
```

and here are the above shown EBELN in her "new" state:

```
print(mseg_summiert.loc[mseg_summiert['EBELN'] == '0025284220'])

      DMBTR       EBELN  EBELP
8   3128.28  0025284220  00010
9   6941.42  0025284220  00020
10  6062.41  0025284220  00030
```

i am not really fluent in python, pandas and this kind of programming. i´m pretty sure i did not use the capabilities of my playing field.

Can you please share some thoughts? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post inputs, outputs, intermediate results etc. **as text** and not as images. That is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: Maybe it's just late, but I cannot understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, what i try to accomplish is, that i have a DataFrame with every combination of EBELN and EBELP as just one row instead of several.
i edited the above example to give a clear example.

Comment: It is better if you give a *self-contained* example, use toy-example dataframes.

Comment: But now I think you just want something like `df.groupby('EBELN', 'EBELP')['DMBTR'].sum()`

Comment: That would be possible, but i need to keep the form of the dataframe intact for further joins with other tables.

Comment: From reading through your example, I think that @juanpa.arrivillaga is right. You can make 'EBELN' and 'EBELP' columns again by doing: df.groupby('EBELN', 'EBELP')['DMBTR'].sum().reset_index()

Comment: @scomes you can also pass `as_index=False` to `groupby`